# Should I disable Windows defender when using Avast?

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender, avast

I have windows defender, Avast internet security and MWB, Windows 10, latest update.

Usually Avast automatically disables windows defender, which is expected. But starting from yesterday, defender is running alongside Avast, I don't know why.

All is running smoothly with no conflicts, even after running defender scan. Should I disable defender manually, since the old wisdom says not to run two real time AV, or should I leave it since there's no conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Limited Periodic Scanning enabled in Windows Defender options, Windows Defender would be running a periodic scan (no real-time monitoring by WD, though) when the system is idle. Enabling the option would cause Defender icon to show up in the Notification area.

However, Windows Defender UI would show "Real-time protection: Handled by another AV Program" if Avast is active.